# Beautiful Soup - Cannot find the tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The page is: http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=13015989524
you can see its source code.

In its source code the following code exists

```
<a href="http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=13015989524" target="_blank">
```

But when I use BeautifulSoup to read the source code and execute the following

```
soup.findAll('a', href="http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=13015989524")
```

It returns `[]` empty.  What does it return '[]'?

Comment: could you show a little bit more of your code? how are you retrieving the contents of the URL? if you try to find the string inside the HTML (without using BeautifulSoup) is it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, the `<a>` tag you are trying to find is inside a `<textarea>` tag. BS does not parse the contents of `<textarea>` as HTML, and rightly so since `<textarea>` should not contain HTML. In short, that page is doing something sketchy.

If you really need to get that, you might "cheat" and parse the contents of `<textarea>` again and search within them:

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as BS

soup = BS(urllib.urlopen("http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=13015989524"))

a = []
for textarea in soup.findAll("textarea"):
    textsoup = BS(textarea.text)  # parse the contents as html
    a.extend(textsoup.findAll("a", attrs={"href":"http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=13015989524"}))

for tag in a:
    print tag

# outputs
# <a href="http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=13015989524" target="_blank"><img ...
# <a href="http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=13015989524" title="901 ...
```

Comment: @Moonlight: AFAIK, `<script>` and `<textarea>` are the only ones.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary to store the attribute:

```
soup.findAll('a', {
  'href': "http://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=13015989524"
})
```